# Playing chunck of bytes into MPMoviePlayerController on iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, video, mpmovieplayer

My application is actually downloading a video I can easily read with `MPMoviePlayerController`. But now I have my video split and so on a segment form (meaning I receive a segment.init and then some other segments containing the video such as video_mp4_init.segment, video_mp4_0000.segment, video_mp4_0001.segment etc) in my bundle.

What I am looking for is some help about the way I need to read the bytes. So far I'm reading the same way I read a video:

```
  NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                   pathForResource:@"tos_mp4_media_0000" ofType:@"segment"]];
 MPMoviePlayerViewController *playercontroller = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc]
                                               initWithContentURL:url];
 [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:playercontroller];
 playercontroller.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;
 [playercontroller.moviePlayer play];
```

A black screen launches then quit. I know `MPMoviePlayer` does not read .segment and I do guess this is not the way it should be done but I run out of ideas.

I'd find it a bit odd if `MPMoviePlayer` does not allow the reading of bytes but it might also be a problem. I can swap to another video reader if needed.

Any idea is welcome.

Edited for futher informations.

Comment: Are you downloading the data or is it already in your bundle? If you're downloading it, `- [NSBundle pathForResource:ofType:]` is not going to return its path.

Comment: It is already in the bundle !